# How can I delete doubled words from string in php?

Tags: php

I have a string, for example:

```
$actors = "Anders Olholm, Anders Olholm, Kenneth Bogh Andersen";
```

I need every name just once in a variable. So the expected output would be like this:

```
$actors = "Anders Olholm, Kenneth Bogh Andersen";
```

How can I get the names just once?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: ...although closure as "too broad" is definitely wrong, as the concise complete answer proves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by exploding it into an array, find the unique values, and imploding it again.

```
$actors = "Anders Olholm, Anders Olholm, Kenneth Bogh Andersen";
$array = explode(", ", $actors);
$array = array_unique($array);
$actors = implode(", ", $array);
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/grhXB)

- http://php.net/explode
- http://php.net/implode
- http://php.net/array_unique